# How do we fetch IAM service last accessed details using Boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam

Below is my code before converting to report\csv format

```
client=boto3.client('iam',aws_access_key_id='somedeclaredvariable',aws_secret_access_key='somedeclaredvariable')

users=client.list_users()

for x in users['Users']:

    response = client.generate_service_last_accessed_details(Arn=x['Arn'],Granularity='SERVICE_LEVEL')
    response1=client.get_service_last_accessed_details(JobId=response['JobId'])
    if(response1['JobStatus']!='IN_PROGRESS'):
        print(response1['ServicesLastAccessed'])
```

Output i get doesnt have any data in ServicesLastAccessed list

It is simply an empty list : `[]`

Answer (score 0):

I run your same code in AWS Lambda

```
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    client=boto3.client('iam')

    users=client.list_users()
    print(users)
    
    for x in users['Users']:
    
        response = client.generate_service_last_accessed_details(Arn=x['Arn'],Granularity='SERVICE_LEVEL')
        print(response)
        response1=client.get_service_last_accessed_details(JobId=response['JobId'])
        if(response1['JobStatus']!='IN_PROGRESS'):
            print(response1['ServicesLastAccessed'])
```

`generate_service_last_accessed_details(**kwargs)`

Generates a report that includes details about when an IAM resource (user, group, role, or policy) was last used in an attempt to access AWS services. Recent activity usually appears within four hours.

I was also not getting result for `GenerateServiceLastAccessedDetails` this. But i tried running another Lambda which used same user role. Not this got access after this am able to get result.

```
{'JobId': 'XXXXX', 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'bac90379-dXXXXX', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': 'bac90XXXX', 'content-type': 'text/xml', 'content-length': '395', 'date': 'Thu, 15 Oct 2020 06:40:29 GMT'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

Clearly said `get_service_last_accessed_details(**kwargs)`
Retrieves a service last accessed report that was created using the `GenerateServiceLastAccessedDetails` operation.
**Note** :

- Make sure you have right access for IAM role which going to get user details
- Its give last four hours activities. Tried accessing now and then run this code.

Comment: Yes i tried all the above. Still, the output list seems to be empty. Whereas it produces output when tried for the IAM roles instead of users.

Comment: It worked for 'Users'.. But, unfortunately it works only for few users and not all. Say for ex. 4 out of 10 on a random basis. 

client.generate_service_last_accessed_details(Arn=user_arn)
  get_last_accessed=client.get_service_last_accessed_details(JobId=gen_last_accessed['JobId'])
 
For the remaining users which didn't succeed get_last_accessed['JobStatus']   is always in 'In Progress' status.   

Output would be generated only when it completes. But this seems to be in progress for a infinite period.  Does anyone know why is it so?

Comment: Have a look in AWS console to see if there is anything odd about the failing Roles

Answer (score 0):

I found you have to poll on the result from get_service_last_accessed_details(JobId=) until you get a JobStatus of COMPLETED.

I put in a series of waits to cover the quick response cases, and the slower ones, eg.

```
for job_wait in (0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0):
  response = ...
  status = response.get('JobStatus', '')
  if status == 'COMPLETED':
  .... exit with result
  time.sleep(job_wait)
else:
  # loop completed without getting a result
```